# Lighthouse provides different feedback for http://localhost/app and https://prod.site.com/app

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I am upgrading an existing webapp to a PWA.

When I audit it using lighthouse audits in chrome 62.0.3202.94 (Build officiel) (64 bits), I find different results if I analyse http://localhost/app  or https://prod.site.com/app .

When auditing on localhost, the manifest.json is ok and chrome should propose to install my app. When auditing on https://prod.site.com/app (well, in fact https://qual.site.com/app ;-) ), I have an error with start_url :

Failures : Manifest start_url is not cached by a Service Worker.

I checked and it is cached. As recommended, I added all variants of the home page to my cache configuration ( / , index.html, /index.html,...).

The cache seems to have the same content for http://localhost/app and https://qual.site.com/app .

Of course, the https sites have valid certificates.

What can cause this descrepancy ?

Comment: Which server do you use? Is it the same for both urls?

Comment: On  http://localhost/app , it is apache.
On  http://localhost:<port>/app , it is tomcat 8.5

On https://prod.site.com/app , it is only tomcat 8.5.